# Limit the number of file handles opened by the JVM to read dependency JARs

Tags: java, jvm, jetty

I am running a Java web application in one of these centralized business something environments. This works fine for a while, the application uses Jetty to run but I quickly run out of file handles. I first thought, there was something seriously broken in the environment since I suddenly got `NoClassDefFoundError`s. However, I then found that the `ClassLoader` in the JDK actually throws this exception when it tries to load a class but cannot get a handle on the *.class* file that contains the class's data. I thus thought that the application had a handle leak which I tried to debug. The managed environment is quite restrictive on the number of concurrent handles.

When trying to debug this, I found that it is indeed the JVM itself that keeps these handles open. Jetty saves the dependencies of the application (with the transitive dependencies of only Spring, those are quite a lot) on the file system something like this

```
...temp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8080_myapp.war_spring_something.jar
```

where the JVM keeps an open file handle to this dependency and others. This way, the JVM keeps about 50 open handles what is too much when I add the handles that the application itself requires (web sockets, database, files).

Before I even begin to discuss the configuration of the precious service bus, I wanted to know if this is:

- normal
- avoidable

I personally find that the JVM should close such handles once it does not actively load classes. I suspect however that this is some optimization technique, in order to avoid constant opening of the jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in an old version of Jetty. Updating to a newer version made the problem disappear.